# How to put for loop output as a new array input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is a part of my code.I did this example code to take a sum of all values of "spe2" as a result of sum. For that what I need to do?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;

    public class  LoopArray{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double t1=3;
            double w=12;
            double t=6;

            int[] intArray = new int[] {4, 4, 2, 1, 1};
             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray)); 

             for (int j = 0; j < intArray.length; ++j){
             double x= (t/intArray[j]);
             System.out.println("x is="+x); 

             double  spe=((float) Math.log10(x));
             System.out.println("spe is="+spe); 

             double spe2= 0.8*spe;
             System.out.println("spe2 is="+spe2); 

  sum of spe2 all values??

             }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could replace: `double[] spe3 = new double[] {?????}`

with

```
double[] spe3 = new double[intArray.length];

for(int a = 0; a < intArray.length; a++) {
spe3[a] = intArray[a];
}
```

However, your logic is flawed. If you want to do this, why not just make intArray a double array to begin with and then it won't be needed to be loaded into a new double array and you can just keep manipulating the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But this is not what I wanted. In above code,  I need to get  final output as a sum of the all "spe2" values. (Please ignore the lower part, I add it for try to do this calculation)